# Matrix multiplication and exponents

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say I have $3\times3$ matrix $A$, which is known.  I'm given $A^x$ and $A^y$.  The goal is to determine $A^{xy}$.  $x$ and $y$ are unknown. Is it possible?

Comment: If the matrix is diagonalizable powers are easy. Do you know if you can diagonalize your matrix?

Comment: @Wintermute Does that mean if the matrix can be Gauss-Jordaned so that everything outside the main diagonal is 0?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman no, this is *matrix similarity*, not *row-reduction* ("Gauss-Jordaning").

Comment: Euh...A brute-force solution: since the characteristic polynomial of A is of degree $3,$ we can always compute explicitly (at least theoretically) the powers $A^n,$ so we can conversely obtain the values of $x$ and $y$... Of course this is not what you want. :P

Comment: @CaptainCodeman I'm not quite sure what you mean by Gauss-Jordaned. A matrix is diagonalizable if you can write it $A=P^{-1}DP$ for some diagonal matrix D. Then we have the nice result $A^x=P^{-1}D^xP$, which is great because it's easy to raise a diagonal matrix to a power.

Comment: At the very least, it suffices to find only $y$ (or only $x$), then take $(A^x)^y$ (or $(A^y)^x$).

Comment: Brute force will not work.. x and y are millions of digits long.  (Arithmetic is done mod m).  OK I see that if the matrix is diagonalizable it makes it easier to compute $A^x$ but will that help solve the problem?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman It also makes it easy to compute $x$ using logs

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How can you compute x?

Comment: Actually, if you're doing arithmetic mod $m$, what you would need some sort of [discrete logarithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm).  So no, it isn't that easy after all.